# Should "uncomment" include a hyphen, or is either one correct?

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Should "uncomment" include a hyphen like this: "un-comment", or either one correct?

Comment: Yeah. I saw that one, and they use "uncomment" in there, but it's not the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of *un* as a prefix is part of normal grammar, and it is typically used without a hyphen when it precedes a word starting with a consonant. In looking at the Merriam-Webster definition of [*un*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/UN), none of the example sentences use it in a hyphenated form.

Where it *is* used with a hyphen, it's when the word that follows it starts with a vowel, such as [un-American](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/un-American), [un-English](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/un-English), and [un-European](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/un-European), and where not using a hyphen could lead to confusion in interpretation.

[Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uncomment%2C%20un-comment&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuncomment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20-%20comment%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cuncomment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20-%20comment%3B%2Cc0) also shows that *uncomment* is far more common that *un-comment*. (And since people don't speak punctuation, the existence or nonexistence of the hyphen in speech is both irrelevant and nonsensical.)

[image: uncomment]